# iText keeps throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext

I've got one issue with iText right now.
I've created a WindowsForms application with C#, it uses iText for generating pdf files with orders.
I'm using it in my work, just to save some time and simplify my work a bit, but it's only for me.
About a week ago I've started creating another application, this time it's web app with .net core technology.

```
public IActionResult OnPostPrintToPDF()
    {
        byte[] pdfBytes;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Paragraph par;
        par = new Paragraph("Hello world");
        document.Add(par);
        document.Close();
        pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
        return new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
    }
```

When I tried to use iText, there's an exception, even though code looks the same.
I've tried any example source codes and nothing works with console application both .net core and framework, I keep getting the same exception (System.NullREferenceException), even in my first app where everything worked so far.

Stack trace of the exception:

> System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. Source=itext.io
>   StackTrace: at iText.IO.Font.FontCache..cctor()

Any ideas what could happen?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of that exception? And can you switch to English error messages for screen shots? Furthermore, the code in the screen shot and the other code in your question are different. Do both fail the same way? As an aside, if the code did not throw an exception anyways, the `stream.Position = 0` at the position it is now would likely damage the result PDF anyways.

Comment: Yes, both code fail the same way.
I've added exception details in my post

Comment: Just a guess, but the stack trace says the issue is with constructing a `FontCache`.  Does anything in the iText documentation suggest that a `FontCache` must be initialized first, before trying to construct a `Document`?

Comment: This is weird, the font cache does some initialization in static code but that usually occurs without error. Just a wild guess, could it be that there is an issue with the libraries linked into your project? Done versioning issue perhaps? Consider removing and re-adding all references and making sure there itext libraries have matching versions.

Comment: I've figured it out, all I had to do was to tick  that combobox where it says: itext.io.dll
But one more question, when the app finishes properly without any exceptions thrown, do you also got that line in the output section:
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in itext.io.dll
?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this exception.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itext.io
  StackTrace: 
    iText.IO.Font.FontCache..cctor()
```

But I tried to fix this exception!

Try to Install package from NuGet.

> itext7.font-asian

I don't know why, but it works successfully.

This question helped me: [How do I read Japanese characters from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529966/how-do-i-read-japanese-characters-from-a-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related due some sort of cache. I can't really understand what, but as you can see in the code the exceptions was generate when he tried to load fonts from cache. I realized that after having tried the same code to a new project and it worked.

so I cleaned the solution, deleted bin, obj, .vs, killed IIS Express, removed and reinstalled all nuget packages then run again, magically it worked.

then I had to made only a fix to the code: instead of HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument that generates only 15 bytes document i used HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf to generate a full pdf.

Comment: I have the same problem but cleaning didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Kindly add the following namespace and you are good to go.

```csharp
using iText.IO.Font;
```

Really no idea why, but this works fine.