# iText7 null reference exception on PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN) VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, itext7

Hi All: I have a VS2019 console app project that generates PDFs. Everything was working fine a month ago. When I re-opened the project and tried to run it, I am receiving a nullreferenceexception error when trying to create the first font in the PdfDocument.

```
PdfFont bfTimes = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
```

throws:

```
System.NullReferenceException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=itext.io
StackTrace:
 at iText.IO.Font.FontCache..cctor()
```

I've confirmed the PdfDocument exists, and the font above returns "true" for "isRegistered".

Nothing changed in the project, but I did update VSCommunity to 16.11.2 at some point in the past couple of weeks. Is there any way to get a better error description for what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this exception.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=itext.io
  StackTrace: 
    iText.IO.Font.FontCache..cctor()
```

But I tried to fix this exception!

Try to Install package from NuGet.

> itext7.font-asian

I don't know why, but it works successfully.

This question helped me: [How do I read Japanese characters from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529966/how-do-i-read-japanese-characters-from-a-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

i searched for that specific exception error and found this other post from a few weeks ago:

https://csharpforums.net/threads/using-a-winform-to-create-a-pdf-using-itext7.6406/

The suggestion to turn on "just my code" in the debugging options made the error go away like magic :o