# iText - HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf() - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, itext7

I'm using iText to convert html to pdf as follows...

```
public static string HtmlToPdf(string DestinationFilename, string Html, HttpServerUtilityBase server)
    {
        string RelativePath = GetFilePath(server, DestinationFilename, overwrite: false);
        PdfDocument pdf = new(new PdfWriter(server.MapPath(RelativePath)));
        pdf.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Html, pdf, new ConverterProperties().SetBaseUri("/Data/temp/"));
        return RelativePath;
    }
```

However, when `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf()` is executed, I am given a rather generic NullReferenceException - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.

It *does* actually convert the Html to pdf properly, but I would prefer not to put code into production that throws exceptions, but the exception details are not really helpful as far as i can read into them.

full exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=itext.io
StackTrace:
at iText.IO.Font.FontCache..cctor()
```

As you can see it references FontCache, but I am not using FontCache here so I'm not sure what it's looking for.

Note: thought it could be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458869/itext-keeps-throwing-nullreferenceexception) but adding using iText.IO.Font; has not had any effect.

tia.

Comment: What a terrible library... cannot you use something like wkhtmltopdf instead? Adding a `using` statement couldn't possibly alter the code to prevent a NRE magically. The linked question's OP suggests ignoring the NRE altogether

Comment: Break it at that line and check all the parameters for a null value.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i've worked with wkhtmltopdf before, it's a bit frustrating because it has to extract and run on cpp redis everytime you use it and your servers need to have cpp redis installed in order to use it...

Comment: @GHDevOps i did that, all the parameters have a value. so nothin' there unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, can you make your sample minimal and reproducible (attach the sample HTML, get rid of `HttpServerUtilityBase server` declaration)? Also, are you sure this exception is unhandled? Some IDEs show even handled exceptions during debugging, so this might even be expected